# Conxex combinations of max and min

Tags: probability-theory, convex-analysis

Is the following true?

$$α \left( \max_{p\in P}\int g\mathrm dp\right)+\left (1-\alpha \right ) \left(
\max_{q\in Q}\int g\mathrm dq \right )=\max_{z\in\left (\alpha P+\left(1-\alpha \right )Q \right)}\int g\mathrm dz$$

where $P,Q$ are weak* closed convex set of probability measures, $\alph\in(0,1)$ and $g$ is a bounded and measurable function.

Is it true if I substitute the max with the min function?

It seems to me that the answer to both my questions is YES.

Thank you in advance to let me know your opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote by $\def\Prob{\mathop{\rm Prob}}\Prob(X)$ the set of all probiability measures on $X$, which is a weak$^*$ compact convex subset of the dual of the bounded measurable functions on $X$. Given a bounded measurable $g \colon X \to \mathbb R$, the map $\phi_g \colon \Prob(X) \to \mathbb R$, $\phi_g(p) = \int_X g \, dp$ is an affine weak$^*$ continuous functional.

Now, as $P$ and $Q$ are weak$^*$ compact, the maxima exist, let $p \in P$, $q \in Q$, and $r \in (1-\alpha)P + \alpha Q$, such that 
$$ \phi_g(p) = \max_P \phi_g, \quad \phi_g(q) = \max_Q \phi_g, \quad \phi_g(r) = \max_{(1-\alpha)P + \alpha Q} \phi_g $$
Then $(1-\alpha)p + \alpha q \in (1-\alpha)P +\alpha Q$, hence 
$$ \phi_g\bigl((1-\alpha)p + \alpha q\bigr) \le \phi_g(r) $$
which gives, as $\phi_g$ is affine
$$ (1-\alpha)\phi_g(p) + \alpha \phi_g(q) \le \phi_g(r) $$
On the other hand, for some $p' \in P$, $q'\in Q$, we have $(1-\alpha)p' + \alpha q' = r$, hence
$$ \phi_g(r) = (1-\alpha)\phi_g(p') + \alpha\phi_g(q') \le (1-\alpha)\phi_g(p) + \alpha \phi_g(q) $$
which gives 
$$ (1-\alpha)\max_P \phi_g + \alpha \max_Q\phi_g = \max_{(1-\alpha)P+\alpha Q} \phi_g $$
as wished. The same formula for $\min$ can be proved along the same lines (or by replacing $g$ with $-g$ an noting that $\max {\phi_{-g}}= -\min \phi_g $.